# How to get field names of quickbook module using php sdk

Tags: php, sdk, quickbooks

i have running **Quickbook PHP sdk** which is returning data of customers from quickbook .

i want to display field names in list box for field mapping . but i am unable to get the field name . 
 my code is.

```
 $CustomerService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Customer();
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM Customer ";
 $customers = $CustomerService->query($Context, $realm, $sql);
 foreach($customers as $key=>$val){ ?>
     <option value="<?php echo  $key ?>"><?php echo  $key ;?></option>   
<?php }
```

> there is nothing in  $key  . while i can get the value by using

```
 foreach($customers as $key=>$val){  
      echo $val->getDisplayName();  
  }
```

Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intuit does not support getting the keys programatically. Additionally, only fields with values in them will be returned when querying objects, so there's no way to get a full list by querying objects either.

You should instead refer to the documentation:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting

Or better yet, the XSD schema:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0200_dev_guides/accounting/minor_versions